# Generate new public key from hash of a message.

Tags: cryptography, bitcoin, elliptic-curve

This question relates to the application of basic elliptic curve crypto for the needs of a Bitcoin project.

I need to generate a receive address (`contract_public_key`) that is directly associated with another (`issuer_public_key`) and some metadata, `M`, to form a Bitcoin contract.

I will try to put in more general terms...

So we have the following:

```
G is the elliptic curve base point.

issuer_private_key = <some random 256bit scalar>
issuer_public_key = issuer_private_key * G

M = 'Terms of contract bla bla and also includes issuer_public_key for safety'
```

I want a function, GenPub, where:

```
GenPub(issuer_public_key, M) = contract_public_key
```

I want a function, GenPriv, where:

```
GenPub(issuer_public_key, issuer_private_key, M) = contract_private_key
```

such that,

```
contract_public_key = contract_private_key * G
```

Here is my first attempt in pseudo-python:

```
def GenPub(issuer_public_key, M):
    # generate a hash of the message
    e = SHA256(M)

    # create an EC point that is known to both parties
    contract_point =  (e * issuer_public_key)

    # generate a public key for this contract
    return contract_point + issuer_public_key


def GenPriv(issuer_public_key, issuer_private_key, M):
    # generate a hash of the message
    e = SHA256(M)

    # create an EC point that is known to both parties
    contract_point =  (e * issuer_public_key)

    # generate a private key for this contract
    return contract_point + issuer_private_key


# the public key for the contract
contract_private_key = GenPub(issuer_public_key, M)

# the private key for contract
contract_private_key = GenPriv(issuer_public_key, issuer_private_key, M)
```

Feedback much appreciated

Comment: It would be better to put this into semi-formal mathematical form and post it at crypto.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contract_point + issuer_private_key` cannot be computed. `contract_point` is a point on elliptic curve but `issuer_private_key` is just a scalar.

Suppose you want is:

```
def GenPriv(issuer_public_key, issuer_private_key, M):
    # generate a hash of the message
    e = SHA256(M)

    # generate a private key for this contract
    return e + issuer_private_key
```

I am not sure the security of this system. It needs some cryptanalysis. Maybe you can ask help from [crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

In my opinion, I will use a [key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) scheme to negotiate a secret key of the contract.